# Renaming files gives weird result in tcsh

Tags: rename, tcsh, tr

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
setenv LC_ALL de_DE
rm /home/users0/me/master/me/LookupScripts/Sampa/*
foreach f ( /home/users0/me/master/me/LookupScripts/Tokenized/*.txt )
set g = "`basename $f .txt`"
set h = "`echo $g | tr "tokenized" "sampa"`"
cat $f | ./a4.lookup > Sampa/$h.txt
end
```

In `/home/users0/me/master/me/LookupScripts/Tokenized/` I have some `.txt` files which are named `randomnumber_tokenized.txt`. I want to run a script on them and I want to put the output of the script to the folder `Sampa/` and I want to keep `randombumber_` in the file names but I want to rename the `tokenized` part to `sampa`, so that the new files look like `randomnumber_sampa.txt`.

Strangely though in the end the files are not called `randomnumber_sampa.txt` but `randomnumber_samaaaaaa.txt`

I suspect that it is either an issue with tcsh or it is because of the `setenv` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it output the correct name if you put the following in your loop: `echo $f | tr "tokenized" "sampa"`?

Comment: `tr` translates one character at a time, always to one character, except if you use `-d` then it translates to nothing. `tr tokenized sampa` translates t to s, k to m, e to p, and all of d e i n o z to a.  To replace a _string_ with another _string_ use `sed`, in this case `sed s/tokenized/sampa/`. Also: you say "some" filenames are `_tokenized`; note this loop will run `./a4.lookup` for ALL `*.txt` files, but it will change the name only for `_tokenized` and leave the filename unchanged for others. Finally `cat $f | x` is the same as `x <$f` or `<$f x`.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier No, same effect. I still get `samaaaaaa`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 according to what you wrote, shouldn't the files then be named `sampaaaaaa`? I don't get a `p` in the name of the output file.

Comment: @doc:  Simply use `sed` as Dave showed you and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: @Julie Yes, thanks, that worked. I'd still like to know why `tr` gives me such a weird result, because, as I said, I'd expect it to output `sampaaaaaa`

Comment: The problem comes from the `e` being repeated and therefore linked to the last character of the replacement characters.

Comment: `tr` leaves unchanged characters that aren't in the first argument, so your random number and underscore are left unchanged. Characters that are in the first argument, but beyond the length of the second argument, reuse the last character fo the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that `tr` doesn't do what you think it does. `tr` performs *character* replacement, not string replacement. The command `tr "tokenized" "sampa"` replaces `t` by `s`, `o` by `a`, `k` by `m`, (`e` by `p` is overridden by a subsequent occurrence of `e`), and `n`, `i`, `z`, `e` and `d` by `a`.

To perform a string replacement, you can use sed. But that's somewhat inconvenient, and hard to get right. For simple string manipulation, use the shell's string manipulation constructs instead of external tools.

Tcsh lacks string manipulation constructs. But (t)csh has not been a tier-1 command line shell for the past 20 years or so, and [has never been good for scripting](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). Just don't write csh scripts.

Also:

- Never set `LC_ALL` to anything other than `C` (or its synonym `POSIX`). `LC_ALL` overrides all categories and this can cause problems. To set a default for all categories, use `LANG`. But in scripts, `C` is usually what you need except for `LC_CTYPE` (character set) and `LC_MESSAGES` (messages for the user).
- String manipulation in sh is done via [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).
- Plain sh has no string replacement construct, but bash does.
- [Always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C
for f in /home/users0/me/master/me/LookupScripts/Tokenized/*.txt; do
  g="${f##*/}"
  h="${g//tokenized/sampa}"
  ./a4.lookup <"$f" >"Sampa/$h.txt"
end
```

Comment: I would not use tcsh if I did not have to. The scripts I have to use only run in tcsh and with `setenv LC_ALL de_DE` and they are probably older than a decade. Nothing I can do about it. 
The `tr` explaination is nice though. Thanks